# How to make it a program work on every Windows pc?

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I have created a application which connects and performs function to a database. However when I compile and publish the application my clients report a error message while trying to open the file about a missing file.

[image]

So they need to have the connector installed before they can use my application, how can I fix this?

Comment: What installer are you using?

Comment: Take the MySql.Data reference and mark it to copy local in your solution. This will cause the .dll file to be copied to your bin when you build the project (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Or create an installer that installs .net mysql connector. (Already mentioned in an answer by spender)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an installer that ensures this dependency is met. [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) is the normal route here. The WiX tools do not depend on VS, although the VS tools make things a little easier for you.

-or-

In VS, open the references section of your project, find the reference to MySql.Data, go to properties and set "Copy Local" to `true` and rebuild. Now the .dll will be copied to your `bin` folder, ready for redistribution as you see fit.

Comment: Cant just give a .dll along with the file?

Comment: @user2911924: Yes. I prefer an installer when distributing executables. Much neater.

Comment: I read here that it doesnt support c# visual studio express. Might want to tell me how to do it with dll?